# Is there a faster way to perform this VBA macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to consolidate multiple worksheets in Excel into 1 worksheet. I use the consolidated worksheet to run a suite of reports in the same workbook.

- The number of worksheets that need to be consolidated varies - approx 6 to 40 worksheets. I identify the sheets to be consolidated by prefixing them with "Src"
- There are approx 40 other spreadsheets in the same workbook (reports that run off the consolidated worksheet and other calculations)
- The format of each worksheet to be consolidated is the same

I am new to macros so have found some code on the internet to automate the consolidation but by the time I have 12 worksheets or so that need to be consolidated it runs very slowly.

Is there anyway that I am able to speed up this macro?

```
Sub CopyDataWithoutHeaders()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim shLast As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim StartRow As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Clear the consol worksheet except the top row with the headings
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All Data")
DestSh.Rows("5:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents


' Fill in the start row.ie the row in each of the source sheets that contain the data (do not include heading rows)
StartRow = 5

' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
' summary worksheet if worksheet name starts with src.
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If LCase(Left(sh.Name, 3)) = "src" Then

        ' Find the last row with data on the summary
        ' and source worksheets.
        Last = LastRow(DestSh)
        shLast = LastRow(sh)

        ' If source worksheet is not empty and if the last
        ' row >= StartRow, copy the range.
        If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then
            'Set the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))

           ' Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary
           ' worksheet to copy all the data.
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
               MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
               "summary worksheet to place the data."
               GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            ' This statement copies values, and formats.
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

        End If

    End If
Next


ExitTheSub:
Application.GoTo DestSh.Cells(1)

' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: You can switch off calculation and screen updating.

Comment: Try to cut off some declarations like the "StartRow", since it's value is fixed, it's not a variable so just put 5 where she appears, if the vlue dosen't change along the code, there is no need to create a variable for it, it won't get alot faster but it does help

Comment: @YgorYansz actually, in a longer procedure it would make sense to use constant or variable like this - if the value needs updating in the future then you only need to change it once on this line rather than finding every line and replacing the value.

Comment: @SO i know that, i meant in this expecific case, since it only appears two times and it never changes along the code, so it's just for this expecific case

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you have one column where there is no blank row from start to end, try replacing the `LastRow()` function with

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
Dim i as Long, R as Range

    i = 1
    Set R = sh.[A1]

    Do while R(i,1) <> ""    ' we asume column A (.. 1) here
        i = i+1
    Loop

    LastRow = i

End Function
```

Alternatively you can play with the `.CurrentRegion` property to avoid counting rows & columns alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Last = LastRow(DestSh)
shLast = LastRow(sh)
```

with

```
Last = DestSh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
shLast = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

You have a `LastCol(sh)` function, but I'm not actually seeing a call to it. If I'm missing it, you can replace the function call with:

```
sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

Normally, a paste will copy both the values and the formatting, so unless there's something in particular you're trying to avoid, replace:

```
With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
  .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

with

```
DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A").Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Finally, remember that VBA code is interpreted as it executes and will inherently be slower than pre-compiled code. Also, it's still significantly quicker than doing it by hand!

Comment: `Last = DestSh.UsedRange.Rows.Count` assumes that the `UsedRange` starts in row 1, you should use something like `With DestSh.UsedRange: Last = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row: End With` to get the actual row number of the last row in the used range.

Comment: @SO, that is true, and his data starts at `StartRow = 5`, but he does take that into account in his use of `Last` and `shLast`, so worrying about that isn't relevant in _this_ case.

Comment: of course, without seeing the actual data it's all just speculation anyway but thought I would mention it in case someone else comes across this page and uses this answer on a different data set.

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented all of these suggestions and run time has reduced to less than a minute.